# When onRestoreInstanceState is not called?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) describes when `onRestoreInstanceState` IS called:

> This method is called after `onStart()` when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in savedInstanceState. (...)
>   This method is called between `onStart()` and `onPostCreate(Bundle)`. This method is called only when recreating an activity; **the method isn't invoked if `onStart()` is called for any other reason**.

I'm super curious what does "`onStart()` is called **for any other reason**" mean in context of `onRestoreInstanceState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal lifecycle of an `Activity` looks like this:

- onCreate()
- .
- onStart()
- onResume()
- onPause()
- onStop()
- .
- onDestroy()

The lifecycle callbacks between `onStart()` and `onStop()` can occur over and over again if the `Activity` is completely obscured by another `Activity`. In this case, `onStop()` is called when the `Activity` is completely obscured by another `Activity`. When the `Activity` is made visible again, `onStart()` will be called **without `onRestoreInstanceState()` being called** because the `Activity` is not being recreated.

Comment: Ahhhh now I get what they meant! This is quite obvious but written in unfortunate way.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately some of the documentation is not very clear.